# Subversion ignore list

Tags: eclipse, svn, maven-2

I have very basic question about adding a folder in svn ignore list. I have one maven project and it created target folder. Now other developer had checked in this target folder in svn. What I want is when I view the Team synchronization view in eclipse, I dont want eclipse to show target folder in the list. When I try to right click this folder and try to add it in ignore list then it is disabled. Can someone please explain me how can take the folder out of svn list as this target folder will be generated by maven and it does not need to be part of source code in repo?

Answer (score 4):

In general, Subversion uses the ignore list only for files (and directories) which are not yet in the repository. For versioned files, the ignore list is ignored.

So it looks like your only easy way would be to delete this folder from the repository again.  Of course, this should be first discussed in the team.

(There might be some complicated way, but I'm not subversion wizard.)

Comment: Yeah you need to delete it fromt he reop frst then commit the prop add on the parent to ignore the folder.

Answer (score 1):

[Ignore](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html) pattern are only applied on non-versionned item.

To ignore to your folder, you must delete it first, and add a property svn:ignore with the desired pattern.

**Command line:**

```
svn rm MAVEN_DIRECTORY
svn propedit svn:ignore PARENT_DIRECTORY_OF_MAVEN_DIRECTORY
// add the pattern of your directory in the list, and save
svn commit
```

Be advised that once commited, I believe it will delete this directory from every developper working copy, unless there are modification (Test it before to be sure)

Answer (score 1):

Try **Update to HEAD** before trying to add to **Add to svn:ignore**.

Comment: Actually your's and Paŭlo Ebermann's answer are the most correct. +1, thanks, especially your's answer helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I believe ignores need to be committed to the repo to take effect on all users' working copies.  Does that answer part of the question?  I'm not too familiar with SVN in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can delete any folder from SVN. and then doing a commit should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Add bin and target to global svn ignore in Eclipse:

https://confluence.sakaiproject.org/display/BOOT/Add+bin+and+target+to+global+svn+ignore+in+Eclipse